# Changing height and width of highchart svg

Tags: svg, highcharts, height, width

Does anyone know a method of changing the height and width of an svg image of a highchart. I'm getting the svg code using

```
 var svg = chart1.getSVG();
```

The code itself then is :

```
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" style="font-family:'lucida grande', 'lucida sans unicode', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600" height="300"><desc>Created with Highstock 4.2.5</desc><defs><clipPath id="highcharts-11"><rect x="0" y="0" width="517" height="300"></rect></clipPath></defs><rect x="0" y="0" width="600" height="300" fill="#FFFFFF" class=" highcharts- ... etc
```

I've tried changing the height and width properties in this piece of code but it doesn't seem to work properly. I've also tried using the Viewbox method as well but that seems to make it too small. realistically I just need to change the height as the width seems to be okay, but if I could I would like to increase the width a small bit.I'm trying to print the svg in a pdf to show the charts but their not showing up true to their size (which is expected)
Any Ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: How have you " tried changing the height and width properties in this piece of code"? How have you "tried using the Viewbox method"? You need to add your attempts, otherwise we can't see where you're going wrong.

Comment: The svg code above I've just simply changed the height and width values by searching for them and replacing them using php but they still don't come out as expected. Also just adding view box: 0 0 (height*2) (width *2) to the above code @RobertLongson

Comment: Even hard coding different height and width values doesn't seem to give me a realistic outcome unfortunately, I'm just not sure if I'm going about it the wrong way

Comment: Have you tried to change the height and width of the container?

Comment: @morganfree yeah I've tried playing around with that as well but no joy! When I change the height and width values of the above svg code (Lets say make height smaller) it just cuts off part of the image , it doesn't scale

Comment: If you double the width/height of the viewBox you'll make the drawing 1/4 of the size is that what you wanted? I suspect it isn't

Comment: @user you need a viewBox if you want it to scale. Make it have the original width / height and then make the width/height attributes have some new values.

Comment: @RobertLongson if I have an original height of 400 and width of 600 but I want to make the height smaller, technically shouldn't "view box: 0 0 800 600" work to half the height but keep the width the same? thanks for the help by the way!

Comment: Sure if that's what you want. Remember it's viewBox and not viewbox or view box though.

Comment: Couldn't you just use highcharts exporting module in this case?, It has parameters like sourceWidth and sourceHeight that may help you with your problem. See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/d9k1sukb/1/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński I need to add it to a pdf with other information so I can't have the charts on their own pdf, I also need to add them to the pdf without the user actually having to export them manually, unfortunately!

Comment: So maybe you can add your options inside getSVG() method? For example chart.getSVG({chart:{width:300, height:300}}) http://jsfiddle.net/oadxc3hs/

Comment: I have the same problem, the chart keep going down when I resize the window